# Is MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT field value alway greater than 0?

Tags: mysql, sql

When getting ID from a MySQL table with AUTO_INCREMENT column I always check if it strictly greater than 0.
But recently I was thinking, is it a strict rule for AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: What's wrong with 0, and negative id's?

Comment: You cannot create a table with negative AUTO_INCREMENT or set negative value in ALTER TABLE - this causes syntax error. If it is set to 0 in CREATE TABLE then this setting is ignored which is equal that it was set to 1. If you set it in ALTER TABLE with the value which is less than current one then this change is ignored. But you can insert negative value explicitly (this does not change current AUTO_INCREMENT value). See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4e7dd3d09aa846778eaf37ce48205bee

Comment: ' I always check if it strictly greater than 0.' - may be a good idea depending on context..

Answer (score 1):

**Default behaviour**

It's **TRUE** for MySQL and MariaDB databases, unless you made some settings manipulation.
There is no clear statement in MySQL docs:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html
But it can be understood from the description and this phrase:

> To start with an AUTO_INCREMENT value other than 1, set that value
> with CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE, like this

So the default start value is always 1, not 0.
And you can not set the AUTO_INCREMENT column value to 0, unless you set NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_value_on_zero
By the way, its says:

> mysqldump automatically includes in its output a statement that
> enables NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO
> So be careful.

There is an explicit statement in the MariaDB docs:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/

> AUTO_INCREMENT columns start from 1 by default. The automatically
> generated value can never be lower than 0.

**Overflow**

If the value is overflown, it won't set to 0 too:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

> When the column reaches the upper limit of the data type, the next
> attempt to generate a sequence number fails.